# WinForms TableLayout won't Downsize

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono, tablelayoutpanel

Straight to the question ...

---

### Information :

I made this custom User Control (Call it ExpansivePanel) which contains these :

```
- TableLayoutPanel (Call it ProblemTable)
    - Label (C0, R0)
    - Button (C1, R0)
    - Panel (C0, R1, CSpan2)
```

When button is clicked, The panel expands / collapses to show the content.

---

### Problem :

The Problem is, that when I add this as a Control to another container and try to resize it, Things are done correctly down to the **ExpansivePanel**, But starting from the **ProblemTable** it will only resize if new size is bigger than current size, which of course it's contents are also never resized except when their size is growing.
This happens on Linux. On Windows, It only happens when the size set by user is too small.

---

### Things I already tried :

- Setting Anchor instead of Dock on the ProblemTable (+ setting size to ExpansivePanel itself which is required on using Anchors), doesn't really change anything.
- Removing Dock (Fill) property on ProblemTable which makes the table size small (And fixed !) but it's contents are still large and go beneath it !
- Setting Autosize to true on ExpansivePanel which forces it's size to 0 even though it did have containers and controls inside !
- Setting Autosize to true on the ProblemTable which doesn't affect anything at all !
- Setting AutosizeMode on both ExpansivePanel and ProblemTable to different values won't change anything. (Cause there can be no Autosizing here !)
- ... And some other things I don't recall, Cuz I've been trying to figure this out for two days now !!!

---

### Detailed Information :

I'm using both Ubuntu 16.04 (MonoDevelop + Mono/.Net 4.0) and Windows 10 (MonoDevelop-Unity + Mono/.Net 4.0) to build and run this thing. These happen on Linux, But it seems to be fine on Windows unless the size given by user is too small, Which might be natural I think ! Is it ?

Here's the Build method for ExpansivePanel (Containing some Debug code !) :

```
    private void Build ()
    {
        #region Initialization
        this.Cnt_MainTable = new TableLayoutPanel (); // This is the ProblemTable
        this.Lbl_PanelName = new Label ();
        this.Pnl_Content = new Panel ();
        this.Btn_Expanse = new Button ();
        this.Cnt_MainTable.SuspendLayout ();
        this.SuspendLayout ();
        #endregion
        #region Cnt_MainTable
        this.Cnt_MainTable.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Cnt_MainTable.Margin = new Padding(0);
        this.Cnt_MainTable.TabIndex = 1;
        this.Cnt_MainTable.ColumnCount = 3;
        this.Cnt_MainTable.ColumnStyles.Add (new ColumnStyle (SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        this.Cnt_MainTable.ColumnStyles.Add (new ColumnStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        this.Cnt_MainTable.ColumnStyles.Add (new ColumnStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        this.Cnt_MainTable.RowCount = 2;
        this.Cnt_MainTable.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        this.Cnt_MainTable.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        this.Cnt_MainTable.Controls.Add (this.Lbl_PanelName, 0, 0);
        this.Cnt_MainTable.Controls.Add (this.Btn_Expanse, 2, 0);
        this.Cnt_MainTable.Controls.Add (this.Pnl_Content, 0, 1);
        this.Cnt_MainTable.Resize += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (DebugPanel)
            {
                ConsoleLogger.Log ("Content Size = " + Pnl_Content.Size);
                ConsoleLogger.Log ("Label Size = " + Lbl_PanelName.Size);
                ConsoleLogger.Log ("Button Size = " + Btn_Expanse.Size);
            }
        };
        #endregion
        #region Lbl_PanelName
        this.Cnt_MainTable.SetColumnSpan (this.Lbl_PanelName, 2);
        this.Lbl_PanelName.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Lbl_PanelName.Margin = new Padding (0);
        this.Lbl_PanelName.TabIndex = 1;
        this.Lbl_PanelName.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        #endregion
        #region Pnl_Content
        //this.Pnl_Content.AutoSize = true;
        //this.Pnl_Content.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.Cnt_MainTable.SetColumnSpan (this.Pnl_Content, 3);
        this.Pnl_Content.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Pnl_Content.Margin = new Padding (0);
        this.Pnl_Content.TabIndex = 2;
        #endregion
        #region Btn_Expanse
        this.Btn_Expanse.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Btn_Expanse.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.Btn_Expanse.BackgroundImage = ResourceManager.Btn_Hide;
        this.Btn_Expanse.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
        this.Btn_Expanse.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.Btn_Expanse.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        this.Btn_Expanse.Margin = new Padding (0);
        this.Btn_Expanse.Size = new Size (24, 24);
        this.Btn_Expanse.TabIndex = 3;
        this.Btn_Expanse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this.Btn_Expanse.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            IsExpanded = !IsExpanded;
        };
        #endregion
        #region This
        base.Controls.Add (this.Cnt_MainTable);
        this.Cnt_MainTable.ResumeLayout (false);
        this.ResumeLayout (false);
        #endregion
    }
```

And Here's the Build method for ExpansivePanel's Parent which contains a TableLayoutPanel container and adds 3 ExpansivePanels (Pnl_Names, etc.) to it's table.(Incomplete Build - Containing some Debug code !) :

```
private void Build ()
    {
        #region Initialization
        TableLayoutPanel Cnt_Main = new TableLayoutPanel ();
        TableLayoutPanel Cnt_CharID = new TableLayoutPanel ();
        ExpansivePanel Pnl_Names = new ExpansivePanel ();
        ExpansivePanel Pnl_Summaries = new ExpansivePanel ();
        ExpansivePanel Pnl_Attributes = new ExpansivePanel ();
        TableLayoutPanel Tbl_Names = new TableLayoutPanel ();
        TableLayoutPanel Tbl_Summaries = new TableLayoutPanel ();
        TableLayoutPanel Tbl_Attributes = new TableLayoutPanel ();
        this.Lbl_CharID = new Label ();
        this.Cmb_Names_Class = new ComboBox ();
        this.Dtp_Names_Begin = new DateTimePicker ();
        this.Dtp_Names_End = new DateTimePicker ();
        this.Lst_Attributes = new ListBox ();
        this.Lst_Names = new ListBox ();
        this.Lst_Summaries = new ListBox ();
        this.Txt_CharID = new TextBox ();
        this.Txt_Names = new TextBox ();
        this.Btn_Names_Add = new Button ();
        this.Btn_Names_Remove = new Button ();
        this.SuspendLayout ();
        #endregion
        #region Cnt_Main
        Cnt_Main.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Cnt_Main.ColumnCount = 1;
        Cnt_Main.ColumnStyles.Add (new ColumnStyle (SizeType.Percent, 100f));
        Cnt_Main.RowCount = 5;
        Cnt_Main.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Cnt_Main.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Cnt_Main.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Cnt_Main.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Cnt_Main.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Cnt_Main.Controls.Add (Cnt_CharID, 0, 0);
        Cnt_Main.Controls.Add (Pnl_Names, 0, 1);
        Cnt_Main.Controls.Add (Pnl_Summaries, 0, 2);
        Cnt_Main.Controls.Add (Pnl_Attributes, 0, 3);
        Cnt_Main.AutoScroll = true;
        Cnt_Main.Resize += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Cnt_Main.AutoScrollMinSize = Cnt_Main.PreferredSize;
            ConsoleLogger.Log ("PnlN Size : " + Pnl_Names.Size);
            //ConsoleLogger.Log("PnlS Size : " + Pnl_Summaries.Size);
            //ConsoleLogger.Log("PnlA Size : " + Pnl_Attributes.Size);
        };
        #endregion
        #region Cnt_CharID
        Cnt_CharID.AutoSize = true;
        Cnt_CharID.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Cnt_CharID.ColumnCount = 2;
        Cnt_CharID.ColumnStyles.Add (new ColumnStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Cnt_CharID.ColumnStyles.Add (new ColumnStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Cnt_CharID.RowCount = 1;
        Cnt_CharID.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Cnt_CharID.TabIndex = 1;
        Cnt_CharID.Controls.Add (this.Lbl_CharID, 0, 0);
        Cnt_CharID.Controls.Add (this.Txt_CharID, 1, 0);
        #endregion
        #region Lbl_CharID
        this.Lbl_CharID.AutoSize = true;
        this.Lbl_CharID.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Lbl_CharID.TabIndex = 1;
        this.Lbl_CharID.Text = Locale.Language.Strings.Tab_Editor_Character_Label_ID;
        this.Lbl_CharID.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        #endregion
        #region Txt_CharID
        this.Txt_CharID.AutoSize = true;
        this.Txt_CharID.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Txt_CharID.TabIndex = 2;
        #endregion
        #region Pnl_Names
        Pnl_Names.DebugPanel = true;
        Pnl_Names.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Pnl_Names.TabIndex = 2;
        Pnl_Names.Controls.Add (Tbl_Names);
        Pnl_Names.Title = Locale.Language.Strings.Tab_Editor_Character_Panel_Names_Title;
        Pnl_Names.OnExpand += () =>
        {
            Cnt_Main.Size = Cnt_Main.PreferredSize;
        };
        Pnl_Names.OnCollapse += () =>
        {
            Cnt_Main.Size = Cnt_Main.PreferredSize;
        };
        #endregion
        #region Tbl_Names
        Tbl_Names.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Tbl_Names.ColumnCount = 2;
        Tbl_Names.ColumnStyles.Add (new ColumnStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Tbl_Names.ColumnStyles.Add (new ColumnStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Tbl_Names.RowCount = 5;
        Tbl_Names.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Tbl_Names.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Tbl_Names.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Tbl_Names.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Tbl_Names.RowStyles.Add (new RowStyle (SizeType.AutoSize));
        Tbl_Names.Controls.Add (Lst_Names, 0, 0);
        Tbl_Names.Controls.Add (Txt_Names, 1, 0);
        Tbl_Names.Controls.Add (Cmb_Names_Class, 1, 1);
        Tbl_Names.Controls.Add (Dtp_Names_Begin, 1, 2);
        Tbl_Names.Controls.Add (Dtp_Names_End, 1, 3);
        Tbl_Names.Controls.Add (Btn_Names_Add, 0, 4);
        Tbl_Names.Controls.Add (Btn_Names_Remove, 1, 4);
        #endregion
        #region Lst_Names
        Tbl_Names.SetRowSpan (Lst_Names, 4);
        Lst_Names.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        #endregion
        #region Txt_Names
        Txt_Names.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        #endregion
        #region Cmb_Names_Class
        Cmb_Names_Class.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        #endregion
        #region Dtp_Names_Begin
        Dtp_Names_Begin.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        #endregion
        #region Dtp_Names_End
        Dtp_Names_End.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        #endregion
        #region Btn_Names_Add
        Btn_Names_Add.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Btn_Names_Add.Text = Locale.Language.Strings.Button_Label_Add;
        #endregion
        #region Btn_Names_Remove
        Btn_Names_Remove.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Btn_Names_Remove.Text = Locale.Language.Strings.Button_Label_Remove;
        #endregion
        #region Pnl_Summaries
        Pnl_Summaries.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Pnl_Summaries.TabIndex = 3;
        Pnl_Summaries.Controls.Add (Tbl_Summaries);
        Pnl_Summaries.Title = Locale.Language.Strings.Tab_Editor_Character_Panel_Summaries_Title;
        Pnl_Summaries.OnExpand += () =>
        {
            Cnt_Main.Size = Cnt_Main.PreferredSize;
        };
        Pnl_Summaries.OnCollapse += () =>
        {
            Cnt_Main.Size = Cnt_Main.PreferredSize;
        };
        #endregion
        #region Pnl_Arrtibutes
        Pnl_Attributes.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Pnl_Attributes.TabIndex = 4;
        Pnl_Attributes.Controls.Add (Tbl_Attributes);
        Pnl_Attributes.Title = Locale.Language.Strings.Tab_Editor_Character_Panel_Attributes_Title;
        Pnl_Attributes.OnExpand += () =>
        {
            Cnt_Main.Size = Cnt_Main.PreferredSize;
        };
        Pnl_Attributes.OnCollapse += () =>
        {
            Cnt_Main.Size = Cnt_Main.PreferredSize;
        };
        #endregion
        #region This
        this.Resize += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
        {
            ConsoleLogger.Log ("Table Size : " + Cnt_Main.Size);
        };
        this.Controls.Add (Cnt_Main);
        this.PerformLayout ();
        this.ResumeLayout (false);
        #endregion
    }
```

---

### Screenshots :

```
// Sorry I'm not allowed to add more than 2 hyperlinks ! //
```

- Initial State. **(i.stack.imgur.com/uOhWC.png)** Nothing has happened yet. Just Build methods.
- [First time Downsize.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCLCz.png) Contents of table hide beneath it. The one which its size is not changing is the ProblemTable (aka. Cnt_MainTable in ExpansivePanel).
- [Growing after Downsize.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQAMM.png) The table resizes and it's contents resize to fit the table size. There's no problem here.
- Second time downsize. **(i.stack.imgur.com/m47uH.png)** Table won't resize since last grow but it's parent does, Making the table hide beneath it's parent.

Comment: What does this have to do with Mono? Tag removed.

Comment: As I mentioned, I compiled it using Mono on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Sorry, didnt see. Good luck with WInForms on Mono.